# GIS or Remote Sensing technique to map sub-surface features?

Tags: remote-sensing, watershed

I am trying to delineate agriculture [tile drainage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tile_drainage) in Midwest.

Does anyone know of any GIS and/or sub-surface remote sensing techniques to detect tiles/objects buried in shallow depth of soil?

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what type of remote sensing can be used to detect subsurface features?

I can think of [ground penetrating radar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground-penetrating_radar) (GPR).

Comment: My first thought when I read the title was the GPR like you mentioned. I would go for that. I had a look at [Similar Technologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground-penetrating_radar#Similar_technologies) on the Wikipedia page of Ground-penetrating RADAR and I still think that the GPR would be the most appropriate tool.

Comment: Theres a book probably on the topic: Remote Sensing of Energy Fluxes and Soil Moisture Content by George P. Petropoulos ; https://www.crcpress.com/Remote-Sensing-of-Energy-Fluxes-and-Soil-Moisture-Content/Petropoulos/9781466505780 . But it's expensive. Maybe a library next to you has it? My google search terms for finding this were "remote sensing water content".

Comment: With (very) dry, bare soils, satellite sythetic aperture radar could work and has been used to find dry river beds, etc. Depending on the resolution it could be feasible. Another option is to look at interferometric coherence; I've seen sub-surface features crop up as higher coherence in short interferometric pairs.